# Auto generate a showroom page for python notebooks

Tags: documentation, shogun

I wanted to generate a showroom page for my jupyter notebooks using a continuous integration tool like [Travis](http://travis-ci.org).

A perfect example is [Shogun's showroom page](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/showroom) but I don't know what they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are using buildbot to generate it; here's the job for it:
http://buildbot.shogun-toolbox.org/builders/nightly_default/builds/44

the content of the generate notebook is pretty straightforward:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/build_install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/build_install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

find $1 -type f \( -name '*.ipynb' ! -name 'template.ipynb' \) | xargs -I{} cp '{}' $3
find $1 -type f \( -name '*.ipynb' ! -name 'template.ipynb' \) | xargs -P $2 -I{} jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --to html --output-dir $3 --execute '{}'
find $3 -type f -name '*.html' | xargs -P $2 -I{} python extract_image_from_html.py '{}'
```